# Flutter driver Test Explorer

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, integration-testing, intellij

is there a way to get some kind of Flutter Test Explorer into the IntelliJ IDE?

I am thinking of something like JUnit has in Visual Studio. Let's say that it should be something like this. My tests are stored in Feature Files.

[image]

If yes please send me a link to an addon or tool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Flutter Dart tests are supported out-of-the-box by IntelliJ. Maybe reading this article helps: https://medium.com/flutter/running-unit-tests-as-part-of-your-everyday-flutter-workflow-979970570fd4

[image]

Comment: yes I know about this one... but this shows your tests after the execution. By that question I meant something what can see the testing scenarios before the execution and/or you can select which scenario should be executed